# What is the function of から in this sentence?

Tags: song-lyrics, conditionals, particle-から, japanese-to-english, context

I found this sentence in the lyrics of a song:

> 振り返れ**ば**もう戻れない**から**

I don't understand the context and the function of から placed in this sentence.

The song is this:

http://m.kget.jp/lyric.php?song=260055

Comment: "There's no going back"  In English, we can just throw a phrase out like that. Japanese likes to provide more context.  If, in Japanese, you're providing an explanation, you throw in a から or んだ or something to make clear, "I'm explaining myself".  But even in these lyrics you could say in English, "'cuz there's just no going back".

Comment: Thanks a lot. 